# How to calculate difference between two 3D models(.obj) in python?

Tags: python, 3d, distance

I have two .obj 3D models (see two images) and I want to calculate the differences between the two 3D models. How should I achieve this in python, or if there are any other ways? I have heard of the  Hausdorff distance but I have no idea how to implement it with .obj files

I have uploaded the .obj files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1REkQJfqlIhIp98RmwP4J7_51hZwkiqjM?usp=sharing).

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]
[image]